# Using datetime.strptime, why, when I input the year as “20” does it display the year as 2020 as opposed to 1990?

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
>>> from datetime import datetime 
>>> datetime.strptime("6/3/20, 9:51:45", "%d/%m/%y, %H:%M:%S")                                                                                                                                                                             
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 6, 9, 51, 45)
```

For the above code can someone tell me why the year output is 2020 when there are several possible years like 1920? On what basis it is picking 2020?

Comment: It's gotta pick something. It can't give you every possibility.

Comment: It appears the cutoff is 00-68 = 2000s and 69-99 = 1900s

Comment: @alec, nice observation. Tried to look into the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py) of datetime module, though I'm not good at reading codes, but found this line ```_EPOCH = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)```, it might have something to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `strptime()` in Python (both for `time.strptime()` and `datetime.datetime.strptime()` follows the [Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX) standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), and it's that standard that specifies the behaviour here.

The [POSIX standard for `strptime()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) states what happens when you use `%y` on a 2-digit value:

> `%y`
>   The year within century. **When a century is not otherwise specified, values in the range [69,99] shall refer to years 1969 to 1999 inclusive, and values in the range [00,68] shall refer to years 2000 to 2068 inclusive**; leading zeros shall be permitted but shall not be required.

Your input uses `20`, which falls in the range [00,68], inclusive.

If you want to see this in the source code, you need to look at the [`Lib/_strptime.py` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/03ac090c5f8d5b281e56c5f5431c1754fd4efe5c/Lib/_strptime.py#L375-L383):

```
if group_key == 'y':
    year = int(found_dict['y'])
    # Open Group specification for strptime() states that a %y
    #value in the range of [00, 68] is in the century 2000, while
    #[69,99] is in the century 1900
    if year <= 68:
        year += 2000
    else:
        year += 1900
```